# Creating directory in FTP

Tags: vb.net, ftp, ftpwebrequest

i am using the following piece of code to create a directory.
The problem is that i do not get an error, but i do not also find the directory i justt created.

So, what am i doing wrong here? Should i take a break?

```
 Public Function CreateDirectory(ByVal Dir As String) As Boolean
        Dim myftprequest As Net.FtpWebRequest = CType(FtpWebRequest.Create(FTPSite + Dir), FtpWebRequest)
        myftprequest.Credentials = New NetworkCredential(UserName, Password)
        myftprequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.MakeDirectory
        Return True
    End Function
```

Comment: I'm not really sure about vb.net syntax, but are you actually *calling* the `MakeDirectory` function somewhere in there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not really a VB person so this syntax might be a bit off but I believe you're missing something along the lines of:

```
Dim myFtpResponse As Net.FtpWebResponse = CType(request.GetResponse(), FtpWebResponse)
```

Otherwise you're never actually DOING anything with the request except for creating it.

Comment: Oups! Someone forgot... Dim response As FtpWebResponse = CType(myftprequest.GetResponse, FtpWebResponse)

Comment: Sorry about that. I just upvoted. After all it is free of charge! Thank you.